# Issues with calling function from template

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In one case I have a problem with running a function on the Controller from the template. The value becomes a string containing the function signature, not the value that should be returned from the function.

When I use `{{ getSomeObject(d) }}` in my template markup it works fine, and it prints the object values, meaning that the function got called on the Controller.

I have tried with and without the `{{ }}`.

Pseudo code:

```
<div class"xyz" data-lav-fact="getSomeObject(d)"> <!-- Does not work here -->
    {{ getSomeObject(d) }} <!-- Works here -->
</div>
```

And of course the function is added to the scope in the Controller:

```
$scope.getSomeObject = function(data) {
    return { key: "test" };
};
```

This works in other parts of the application and I don't know what wrong in this case.
Does anyone know what typically can be wrong here?

Comment: What does the directive `lavFact` look like?  I imagine if you remove the `data-lav-fact="getSomeObject(d)"` it would work, so the issue is within the directive and how it's transposing the data.

Comment: really need some more details for this...

Comment: ... specifically how the isolate scope for the lavFact directive is defined.

Comment: Can you throw your full code into a splunker?

Comment: have you made any forward progress on this? Was my answer of any help? Feedback would be appreciated so we can try to help solve this for you

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to set an attribute with a `$scope` function, you'll need to [`{{ interpolate }}`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interpolate) and use [`ngAttr` attribute bindings](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Here is a simple example that shows this in action. Examine the difference between the elements logged out. As you dig, you'll see your `{ key: 'test' }` value being set

```
<div id="without" data-lav-fact="getSomeObject()">without</div>
<div id="with" ng-attr-data-lav-fact="{{ getSomeObject() }}">with</div>
```

---

```
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.getSomeObject = function() {
        return { key: 'test' };
    }

    var w = angular.element(document.getElementById('with'));
    var wo = angular.element(document.getElementById('without'));

    console.log(w[0].attributes);  // has value
    console.log(wo[0].attributes); // does not have value
}]);
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/vfpvjdtz/)